# Is there a way to fix exception in thread for dividing zero?

Tags: java

When I input 3,0,3.14,0, I get the error message. It seems like I'm diving by zero in lines 26,27, and 31. I know it is throwing the arithmetric exception. I need to use the if statements first to check for that case before I try to do any division that i'm doing after. So, the last if statement i have no idea what to do to fix it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathTest 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
            System.out.print("Input integer value 1: ");
            int iNum1 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Input integer value 2: ");
            int iNum2 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Input double value 1: ");
            double dNum1 = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Input double value 2: ");
            double dNum2 = input.nextDouble();
            
            int add = iNum1 + iNum2;
            int sub = iNum1 - iNum2;
            int multi = iNum1 * iNum2;
            int div = iNum1 / iNum2;
            int mod = iNum1 % iNum2;
            double add2 = dNum1 + dNum2;
            double sub2 = dNum1 - dNum2;
            double multi2 = dNum1 * dNum2;
            double div2 = dNum1 / dNum2;
            
            int add3 = iNum2 + iNum1;
            int sub3 = iNum2 - iNum1;
            int multi3 = iNum2 * iNum1;
            int div3 = iNum2 / iNum1;
            int mod3 = iNum2 % iNum1;
            double add4 = dNum2 + dNum1;
            double sub4 = dNum2 - dNum1;
            double multi4 = dNum2 * dNum1;
            double div4 = dNum2 / dNum1;
            
            if (iNum1 > iNum2 || dNum1 > dNum2)
            {
            System.out.println("\nInteger output:");
            System.out.printf("Adding " + iNum1 + " and " + iNum2 + " = " + add);
            System.out.printf("\nSubtracting " + iNum1+ " and "+ iNum2+ " = " + sub);
            System.out.printf("\nMultiplying " + iNum1+ " and "+ iNum2+ " = " + multi);
            System.out.printf("\nDividing " + iNum1 + " and " + iNum2 + " = " + div);
            System.out.printf("\nModing " + iNum1 + " and " + iNum2 + " = " + mod);
            
            System.out.println("\n\nDouble output:");
            System.out.printf("Adding " + dNum1 + " and " + dNum2 + " = %.2f%n", add2);
            System.out.printf("Subtracting " + dNum1 + " and " + dNum2 + " = %.2f%n", sub2);
            System.out.printf("Multiplying " + dNum1 + " and " + dNum2 + " = %.2f%n", multi2);
            System.out.printf("Dividing " + dNum1 + " and " +  dNum2 + " = %.2f%n", div2);
            }
            
            else if (iNum1 < iNum2 || dNum1 < dNum2)
            {
                System.out.println("\nInteger output:");
                System.out.printf("Adding " + iNum1 + " and " + iNum2 + " = " + add3);
                System.out.printf("\nSubtracting " + iNum1 + " and "+ iNum2+ " = " + sub3);
                System.out.printf("\nMultiplying " + iNum1 + " and "+ iNum2+ " = " + multi3);
                System.out.printf("\nDividing " + iNum1 + " and " + iNum2 + " = " + div3);
                System.out.printf("\nModing " + iNum1 + " and " + iNum2 + " = " + mod3);
                
                System.out.println("\n\nDouble output:");
                System.out.printf("Adding " + dNum1 + " and " + dNum2 + " = %.2f%n", add4);
                System.out.printf("Subtracting " + dNum1 + " and " + dNum2 + " = %.2f%n", sub4);
                System.out.printf("Multiplying " + dNum1 + " and " + dNum2 + " = %.2f%n", multi4);
                System.out.printf("Dividing " + dNum1 + " and " +  dNum2 + " = %.2f%n", div4);
            }
            
            if (iNum1 == iNum2 || dNum1 == dNum2)
            {
                System.out.println("\nInteger output:");
                System.out.printf("Adding " + iNum1 + " and " + iNum2 + " = " + add);
                System.out.printf("\nSubtracting " + iNum1 + " from itself "+ " = " + sub);
                System.out.printf("\nSquaring " + iNum1 + " = " + multi);
                System.out.printf("\nDividing " + iNum1 + " and " + iNum2 + " = " + div);
                System.out.printf("\nModing " + iNum1 + " and " + iNum2 + " = " + mod);
                
                System.out.println("\n\nDouble output:");
                System.out.printf("Adding " + dNum1 + " and " + dNum2 + " = %.2f%n", add2);
                System.out.printf("Subtracting " + dNum1 + " from itself " + " = %.2f%n", sub2);
                System.out.printf("Squaring " + dNum1 + " = %.2f%n", multi2);
                System.out.printf("Dividing " + dNum1 + " and " +  dNum2 + " = %.2f%n", div2);
            }
            if (iNum2 == 0 || dNum2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("\nInteger output:");
                System.out.printf("Adding " + iNum1 + " and " + dNum2 + " = " + add);
                System.out.printf("\nSubtracting " + iNum1+ " and "+ dNum2 + " = " + sub);
                System.out.printf("\nMultiplying " + iNum1+ " and "+  dNum2 + " = " + multi);
                System.out.println("Error: You cannot divide and mod by zero!!!");
                
                System.out.println("\n\nDouble output:");
                System.out.printf("Adding " + dNum1 + " and " + dNum2 + " = " + add);
                System.out.printf("Subtracting " + dNum1 + " and " + dNum2 + " = " + sub);
                System.out.printf("Multiplying " + dNum1 + " and " + dNum2 + " = " + multi);
                System.out.println("Error: You cannot divide by zero!!!");
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to be specific.  Where is the last if statement you are talking about?

Comment: @WJS There isn't one. I don't know what to do with last if statement.

Comment: Before you do any division: `if (iNum2 != 0) { int div = iNum1 / iNum2; } else { System.out.println("You can not divide by 0!"); }`.

Comment: Could you please put the complete stack trace into the question. And could you also put comments indicating which lines were the numbered ones you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this when you do the division.  It will silently fail.

```
double dNum2 = 10;
double dNum1 = 0;
double div4 = 0;
try {
    div4 = dNum2 / dNum1;
} catch (ArithmeticException ae) {
}
```

Normally it is considered bad practice to ignore caught exceptions.  But since you are warning about it below, it should be okay.

Comment: If I do double, wouldn't it cause error from double dNum2 = input.nextDouble(); and also what is double dNum2 - 10 for

Comment: I was just assigning 10 to dNum2 to demonstrate catching the exception. Why do you think `input.nextDouble()` would cause a divide by zero exception?

Comment: because it will make duplicate local variable for dNum2

Comment: it has to display like... it has to display like this...

Input integer value 1: 3
Input integer value 2: 0
Input double value 1: 3.14
Input double value 2: 0

Integer output:
Adding 3 and 0 = 3
Subtracting 3 and 0 = 3
Multiplying 3 and 0 = 0
Error:  You cannot divide and mod by zero!!!

Double output:
Adding 3.14 and 0.00 = 3.14
Subtracting 3.14 and 0.00 = 3.14
Multiplying 3.14 and 0.00 = 0.00
Error:  You cannot divide by zero!!!

Comment: *because it will make duplicate local variable for dNum2* As I said before, this was just an example.  You need to apply it appropriately to your code.  Or just do what @DevilsHnd said above.